# NSTableView viewFor tableColumn delegate method not called

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, nstableview

In code I have something like this:

```
let scrollView = NSScrollView()
let tableView = NSTableView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do view setup here.

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.headerView = nil

    scrollView.documentView = tableView
    scrollView.hasVerticalScroller = true

    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

}
```

Both required methods (`numberOfRows` and from the title) are declared. TableView is visible in view, scrollable and selectable. `tableViewSelectionDidChange` works properly, I can get index of selected row by `tableView.selectedRow`. But all cells are empty, because `tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int)` called for none of the cells. I think, the problem is that tableView can't figure out which of the cells are visible right now. But I don't know what I should do with that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I struggled for a moment, but it became clear quickly. The `tableView` generated by you is fine.

The only thing that is missing is a column.
You can simply add one column:

```
tableView.addTableColumn(NSTableColumn(identifier: "Column"))
```

Table Views display their views inside columns. Most tableViews have only one column and with the header hidden, we forget that they even exist.

Without any column, everything else works still normally. BackgroundRows load and selection works - which made me get to this solution.

Comment: maybe, you can help me with another, but related question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40688353/what-replacement-for-uitableviewautomaticdimension-should-i-use-to-get-the-same

Comment: `tableView.addTableColumn(NSTableColumn(identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("idString")))`