# What replacement for UITableViewAutomaticDimension should I use to get the same effect in NSTableView?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

In iOS projects I do something like that:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 30
```

and have nicely resizing cells.

What should I do to reproduce the same behaviour in macOS project?

---

Ok, `func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, heightOfRow row: Int) -> CGFloat`.

Should I configure my SubView (cell view) (that actually is NSView) twice...

In both methods - `heightOfRow` and `viewFor tableColumn`?

I heard about reusing of cells, but can it be done without nibs?

Anyway, if I doing so I get not quite the intended result.

Delegate/Datasource:

```
let items = ["second label",
             "second label with alotoftext alotof...", // long line
             "second label"]

func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, heightOfRow row: Int) -> CGFloat {
    let cell = SubView(text: items[row])
    cell.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()
    return cell.frame.size.height
}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    return SubView(text: items[row])
}
```

SubView:

```
init(text: String) {
    super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

    let text1 = NSTextField(labelWithString: "first label")
    let text2 = NSTextField(labelWithString: text)

    text2.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    text2.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(100, for: .horizontal)

    self.addSubview(text1)
    self.addSubview(text2)

    text1 <- [Top(5), Left(5), Right(5)]
    text2 <- [Top(0).to(text1, .bottom), Left(5), Right(5), Bottom(5)]

}
```

Last two lines are [EasyPeasy](https://github.com/nakiostudio/EasyPeasy) constraints.

So, result is: [image: wrong]

Where is my mistake?

---

And just one more question: what should I do to make cells grow/decrease vertically to fit all subviews inside of them accordingly to resizing width of tableView?

Oh, seem to have realized.

Just added the observer:

```
name: NSNotification.Name.NSViewFrameDidChange,
object: self.scrollView
```

And

```
let vr = scrollView.contentView.visibleRect
let indexes = tableView.rows(in: vr).toRange()!
tableView.noteHeightOfRows(withIndexesChanged: IndexSet(integersIn: indexes))
```

in selector method.

---

Yep. The same view (SubView) works perfect without tableView.
[image] [image]

But I still have the above-described problem with wrong-sized cellViews.

P.S.: Sorry for my english, I hope everything is clear.

Comment: Ok, so your problem is that the cells dont fit the height of the text?

Comment: @mangerlahn yes, cells much larger than they're should be. Suppose, I have two labels in NSView, that I use as viewFor tableColumn. I want that NSview to fit height of this two labels.

Comment: This NSView (SubView) works exactly as I expect outside of tableView (custom view on another view controller, there are screenshots above). But the same view, when it is in tableView, for some reason has much larger height.

Comment: @mangerlahn I wanna get the same behaviour that you can see here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/iq7je72cig69ng5/cell.mov?dl=0 but with multiple cells in the tableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On macOS it is a little more difficult, but not really hard to do. 
There is an excellent answer on this by corbin dunn, the author of `NSTableView` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8054170/4113940).

To put it in a nutshell: 
You need to know the size of your cell and return that value in

```
func tableView(NSTableView, heightOfRow: Int)
```

which is a method from `NSTableViewDelegate`.

**Update 20.11.2016**:

You are almost there! The view you create has no width set. So I guess that the view itself assumes that it is much narrower than the tableView and therefore higher.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, heightOfRow row: Int) -> CGFloat {
    let cell = SubView(text: items[row])
    cell.frame.size.width = tableView.frame.size.width
    cell.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()
    return cell.frame.size.height
}
```

I have not tested this code but it should be it.

Comment: I have a problem with that too. Sure, somewhere I made a mistake, but I can't figure out where. Please, take a look at the updated question

Answer (score 0):

I've added my solution (in Swift 3, with view-based NSTableView and Auto-Layout) here: [View-based NSTableView with rows that have dynamic heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504546/view-based-nstableview-with-rows-that-have-dynamic-heights/42853810#42853810)

Hope that helps you to solve this problem.